# Is there difference for Integer.MAX_VALUE between 32bit JVM and 64bit JVM?

Tags: java, integer

Is the value of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` different between 32bit JVMs and 64bit JVMs?

I am compiling a Java class using 32bit JDK and deploy it on a 64bit machine. I just want to make sure that I can rely on detecting `if (aNumber == Integer.MAX_VALUE)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. By definition `Integer.MAX_VAlUE = 2^31 - 1`

[Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)

Comment: It goes further than that: the *compilation* platform makes **no difference at all**: the output will be the same. In an ideal world even the *runtime* platform would make no difference, but there might be minor differences here.

Answer (score 5):

No. The 32-bit JDK makes 32-bit addresses for the instances, and the 64-bit JDK makes 64-bit addresses for the object instances. Thus, Integer.MAX_VALUE is the same, because it's just an value, not an object address. :)

Comment: Note that a 64bit JVM *can* use 32 bit references. See [CompressedOops](http://wikis.sun.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops) for details.

Answer (score 1):

This constant has the same value regardless of whether the JVM the code is running on is 32-bit or 64-bit.  The [documentation for Integer.MAX_VALUE](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) describes this value as:

> A constant holding the maximum value an `int` can have, 2<sup>31</sup>-1.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to avoid comparing Integers using `=` sign due to:

[Comparing Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur) (provided aNumber is an object of class `java.lang.Integer`)

and no, there is no difference.

Comment: thank you for your extra information. just wondering in what situation do we need to reference check on (Integer == Integer)? Shouldn't we all always just need the value check? So why doesn't someone overload the operator '==' on Integer?

Answer (score 0):

what all 32 bit and 64 bit resembles is the number of memory locations they can refer.. in case of 32 bit possible number of address will be 2^32 and in case of 64 bit it is 2^64.

The jvm version has nothing to do with Integer.MAX_VALUE  , it will remain same.