# Java integers Return Strange Result While Compare Two Integers?

Tags: java, android

```
    Integer i1= new Integer(9);
    Integer i2= new Integer(9);

    if(i1==i2){
        System.out.println("true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("false");
    }


    int i3=9;
    int i4=9;

    if(i3==i4){
        System.out.println("true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("false");
    }

    if(i3==i2){
        System.out.println("true");
    }else{
        System.out.println("false");
    }
```

**In Above Code First if-else print false, Why ?.But when second Return true and also third have true.I think wrapper classes(Like double,boolean,char)cant compare True ?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [When comparing two Integers in Java does auto-unboxing occur?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> First if-else print false. Why?

`==` checks if the two references are referring to the same object, in this case they are not so the `==` check is `false`. You need to use `Integer.equals()`, not `==`:

```
if (i1.equals(i2){
    System.out.println("true");
}else{
    System.out.println("false");
}
```

> Second return true

`==` is correct to use for primitives: `int` is a primitive.

> third have true

As pointed out by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) `i2` is [unboxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html) to an `int` which makes the `if` condition a check between two `int` primitives.

Comment: but what happens with == ?....in boolean we check like isClicked==true it gives Right?

Comment: boolean is primitive, not object, Boolean is an object.

Comment: Primitives such as `boolean`, `int`, etc use `==`, so yes if you have a `boolean` named `isClicked` you are correct to use `isClicked == true`.

Comment: i1 and i2 is two different objects. If you compare them with == it will return false because it is comparing two different object. Where as if you use equals you are comparing the values of the two objects

Comment: If isClicked is a boolean, there is no point in comparing it with another boolean. Just use `if (isClicked)`.

Answer (score 7):

When `==` is used to compare references to objects, it returns true only if both references point to the same object.

In the first case, you have two different objects.

In the second case, you're not comparing objects, but primitive types.

In the third case, the `Integer` object is unboxed to its primitive `int` value to be compared with the primitive value, so two primitive values are compared.

You should never use `==` to compare objects, except for enums. Always use `.equals()`.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you use "==", you are doing a object reference check. That means, the first check will fail since they are 2 different objects.

In the second case, its straight forward.

In the third case, the compiler autoboxes "i2". So, the comparison will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Remember you are not comparing `2 primitives but 2 Objects`.. so Use `.equals()`  method..

Answer (score 0):

The variables `i1` and `i2` refer to Objects, not primitive types. Using the `==` operator on objects in Java checks that the references are equal, if you want to compare them you should use the `.equals()` method.

The comparison of `i3` and `i2` returns true because you're comparing a primitive type (the int `i3`) with a wrapper class for that primitive type (the Integer `i2`), so Java unboxes the value of `i2` to an `int` and then compares them (which does work with the `==` operator).

Answer (score 0):

in first if - you are compare two objects - thay are different. Result = false
in second - you are compare two int values. Result true
in therd - you are compare int and Integer, after unboxing you have two int. Result - true.
for Integer use equals.

Answer (score 0):

The first case, JVM checks whether both i1 and i2 are same reference or not. As they are different so it results false.

The second case, it's no problem as both are primitive data types and have same value, so it's true.

In third case, i2 is first autounboxed and then comparision takes place, so it results true.

Answer (score 0):

With the autocast, `(int)i1==(int)i2` will return true, so will `(i1==i4)`
As the other comments explained it, `==` only compares the objects (which references are passed by value)

Answer (score 0):

another "safe" and alternative way is using the modulo operation

```
 if ( ( i3%i4)==0) System.out.println("true");
```