# Not able to change color of EditText background color dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext, background-color

i am using Edittexts in my application. but not able to set their background color at runtime. If i am doing something wrong then please suggest.

i have taken three edittexts which should change their color according to if codition used in the do while loop. please check and do response ASAp. thanks in advance.

here is my code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



            List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String >>();
            EditText ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
            EditText ed2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
            EditText ed3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            int i = 2;
            EmpDatabase empClick = new EmpDatabase(getApplicationContext());
            Cursor cursor = empClick.getDetails();
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do{
                    i= i+1;
                    if(i % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        // here is something wrong
                        ed1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        ed2.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        ed3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        // here is something wrong
                        ed1.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                        ed2.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                        ed3.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                    }
                    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                    String age = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("age"));
                    String time = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time"));
                    map.put("name",name);
                    map.put("age",age);
                    map.put("time", time);
                    list.add(map);

                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                cursor.close();
            }


            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.text_view, new String [] {"name", "age", "time"}, new int[] {R.id.name,R.id.age, R.id.date});
            setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Comment: hii just use setbackground insted of color and also setcontent view

Comment: Check out that cursor is moved to first. May be if condition is not satisfying.

Comment: there is not cursor problem.. i have taken an integer i to change the color.

Comment: i have tried tried setbackground also.. but didnt work.

Comment: Try this `int j = i%2;`  and use `j.equal("0");`

Comment: tried...didnt work. :(

Comment: equal is used for strings.. not for int values

Comment: any other solution? :?

Comment: Please try something, make a Log after if(cursor.moveToFirst()), for example Log.d("TEST","WORKS"), because if the cursor is empty because You get no data from database, cursor.moveToFirst() returns false and Your operation will never be executet.

Comment: also, if You got only one entry for the cursor, it wont go to next.

Comment: cursor is not empty.. if i remove if els condition.. it works properly.. but i want to put color on edittext background in alternate blocks

Comment: What is meaning of "cursor is not empty..", We are telling you to check out  `if(cursor.moveToFirst())` is satisfied or not. inner code will run only and only if above code will be satisfied.use `else` and `Toast` to check that `if(cursor.moveToFirst())` part is not running.

Comment: which if else condition do You removing to work? The if(cursor.moveToFirst), or  if(i % 2 == 0)?

Comment: if You remove if(cursor.moveToFirst()) and then it works, the cursor must be empty.

Comment: if(i%2==0) condition

Comment: Check out Integer Compare [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9429185/java-integers-return-strange-result-while-compare-two-integers) and [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur) .

Comment: then, follow Dhaval´s hint. The best way is to use the compare method from integer, look at the API : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Integer.html#compare%28int,%20int%29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got answer of this problem.
i made an adapter class which extends simple adapter.. and write following code..

```
public class EmpCustomAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{

    private int[] colors = new int[] { 0x30FF0000, 0x300000FF };

    public EmpCustomAdapter(Context context, List<Map<String, String>> list, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, list, resource, from, to);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        int colorPos = position % colors.length;
        view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

and make its object and set adapter..

```
EmpCustomAdapter adapter = new EmpCustomAdapter(this, list, R.layout.text_view, new String [] {"name", "age", "time"}, new int[] {R.id.name,R.id.age, R.id.date});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
```

and it worked.. :)
thanks to all who helped me to get rid of this issue..:)cant upload result image due to reputation issue.:(

Answer (score 1):

Where is your call to setContentView(YOUR_LAYOUT), basically without this your layout in not generated even generated yet, so findViewById(R.id.name) will result into nothing.

Comment: I think its just a copy paste mistake, if the OP has forgot setContentView, he would see nothing. But he described it like there is no color change instead.

Comment: there is no layout problem.. other than this its working properly, if i remove if else condition.. but dont know why this background color is not changing.

Comment: the only plausible reason i see otherwise is cursor being empty.