# Comparing Integer objects

Tags: java, oop, object

I have the following code:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer alpha = new Integer(1);
        Integer foo = new Integer(1);

        if(alpha == foo) {
            System.out.println("1. true");
        }

        if(alpha.equals(foo)) {
            System.out.println("2. true");
        }

    } 

}
```

The output is as follows:

```
2. true
```

However changing the type of an `Integer object` to `int` will produce a different output, for example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Integer alpha = new Integer(1);
        int foo = 1;

        if(alpha == foo) {
            System.out.println("1. true");
        }

        if(alpha.equals(foo)) {
            System.out.println("2. true");
        }

    } 

}
```

The new output:

```
1. true
2. true
```

How can this be so? Why doesn't the first example code output `1. true`?

Comment: Are you sure that first output is not 2. true? Otherwise, nothing makes sense.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the formatting changed the 2 to a 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [When comparing two Integers in Java does auto-unboxing occur?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1514910/1164465)

Comment: I want to add that in Eclipse you can use FindBugs to catch these mistakes.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

For reference types, `==` checks whether the references are equal, i.e. whether they point to the same object.

For primitive types, `==` checks whether the values are equal.

`java.lang.Integer` is a reference type. `int` is a primitive type.

Edit: If one operand is of primitive type, and the other of a reference type that unboxes to a suitable primitive type, `==` will compare values, not references.

Comment: Thank you, this cleared me up.

Comment: +1 for question and answer. Just to make sure: in situation `(Integer == int)` or `(int == Integer)` it will always be unboxed to `(int == int)` not autoboxed to `(Integer == Integer)`?

Answer (score 7):

Integer objects are objects. This sounds logical, but is the answer to the question. Objects are made in Java using the `new` keyword, and then stored in the memory. When comparing, you compare the memory locations of the objects, not the value/properties of the objects.

Using the `.equals()` method, you actually compare the values/properties of objects, not their location in memory:

`new Integer(1) == new Integer(1)` returns  `false`, while `new Integer(1).equals(new Integer(1))` returns `true`.

---

`int`s are a primitive type of java. When you create an int, all that is referenced is the value. When you compare any primitive type in Java, all that is compared is the value, not the memory location. That is why `5 == 5` always returns true.

When you compare an `Integer` object to a primitive type, the object is cast to the primitive type, if possible. With an `Integer` and an `int` this is possible, so they are compared. That is why `Integer(1).equals(1)` returns true.

Answer (score 2):

What you'll use `new Integer(1)` to create new object, it creates a totally different object each time even though it has the same value. The '==' checks if the objects are same, not data values. In your case, you could have checked the value as follows :

```
if(alpha.intValue() == foo.intValue()) {
 // 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Integer == int here auto boxing applied ( so Integer converted to int before comparision) so true.. but Integer == Integer here object comparison so as reference are different so false..

Answer (score 0):

First example:
Using the == operator between objects checks for reference equality, and since you are comparing two different objects they do not equal.

Second example:
When using the == between a wrapper type (Integer, Long, etc.) and a numeric type (int, long, etc.) the wrapper type is unboxed and the equality check is done between the two primitive numeric types (I.e. between **int** and **int**). The unboxing is part of binary numeric promotion, read more here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2