# primitive int with same value of 2 Integer objects will point to which one of them?

Tags: java, oop, object, integer

```
int a = 30;
Integer b = new Integer(30);
if( b1 == b2)
    System.out.println("Hello");
else
    System.out.println("Hi");
```

> Output :  Hello

Right. As a will also point to integer Object of b. Also explained here : [Comparing Integer objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547201/comparing-integer-objects)

But If I execute :

```
class A2
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int a = 30;
        Integer b1 = new Integer(30);
        Integer b2 = new Integer(30);
        if(a == b1 && a == b2)
            System.out.print("Hello");
        else
            System.out.print("Hi");
        if( b1 == b2)
            System.out.print("Hello");
        else
            System.out.print("Hi");
    } //End of Method
}// End of class
```

> Output : Hello Hi

Second Output is fine as now, b1 and b2 have separate objects. But now where will "a" point to ?? 
Please explain the reason of "Hello" output here.

Comment: [Please see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29139274/how-equal-operator-works-with-primitive-and-object-type-data)

Comment: You answered your question in the first output. As `a` will also point to integer object of `b`. So, in this case as well it's the same.

Comment: An `int` doesn't _point to_ anything! While the value of an `int` might be equal to the value wrapped by some `Integer` instance, the `int` certainly doesn't point to that, or any  other, `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler actually changes it to the following:
if(a == b1.intValue() ){}

Answer (score 0):

If you compare a primitve `int` with an `Integer` the latter get autoboxed to an `int` using the method `intValue()`. If you compare two instances of type `Integer` using `val1 == val2` the reference is compared, which are different here, because you created two different instances of `Integer` containing the same int-value.

Some notes:

Instead of using the constructor, you can create instances of `Integer` by using the `valueOf(int)` method. This method returns cached values if the passed argument is within a particular range (`30` is within it), your two instances would have ended up to be the same in your above example when changing to `valueOf`.

Personally I see autoboxing as a potential source for errors and I actually configured my IDE to regard autoboxing as an error. With above explanation you might already guess, why: Autoboxing is done by using `value.intValue()`. If the value happens to be `null` you end up with a `NullPointerException`. But that's personal taste (and willingness to take risks), so YMMV.

Comment: As a contrasting point, more recent languages than Java (such as Groovy, and possibly the future Java 10) make no distinction between boxed and unboxed types; int and Integer are synonymous. All required boxing/unboxing is done automatically – even when you use `==`.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou I've read about that as well. What happens in the case I mentioned then?

Comment: For example in Groovy `val1 == val2` is equivalent to `val1.equals(val2)` as operators are just syntactic sugar for specific method calls.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou And what happens if `val1` is `null`? In Java you get a `NullPointerException` for the latter statement.

Comment: It would simply return false if val2 is not also null. That's because what happens is a little more complicated than how I explained. It depends on the type of object. For null, it's only ever equal to null. If the object is of a class that implements Comparable, it calls compareTo.