# Comparing Object and int in Java 7

Tags: java, eclipse, compare, java-7, autoboxing

I recently stumbled on a question that made me stop and think...

To me, the code below should always trigger an error, but when one of my colleagues asked me why Eclipse didn't show one, I couldn't answer anything.

```
class A {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(new Object() == 0);
    }
}
```

I've investigated and found that with source level 1.6 it indeed throws an error:

```
incomparable types: Object and int
```

But now in 1.7 it compiles ok.

Please, what new feature does warrant this behavior?

Answer (score 9):

What do you mean by "what new feature does warrant this behavior?" ?  1.7 is fixing an issue present in 1.6.  `new Object() == 0` should have **never** produced an error, and **always** caused autoboxing to trigger.

There was simply no reason why

```
Object a= 5 ;
```

was correct, and not the expression

```
a == 3
```

or even

```
a == 5
```

It was extremely weird and, IMHO, contradictory with the language specification itself.

From a dynamic point of view, though, `a == 5` still evaluates to `false` while `(Integer)a == 5` or even `(int)a == 5` evaluate to `true`.  Reason is that autounboxing was designed to never produce `ClassCastException`s and thus occur for wrapper types only, statically.  The later two cases are explicit casts so `ClassCastException`s are generally allowed.

Comment: Do you mean it now is equivalent with `new Object() == null` and that `new Object() == 2` still triggers an error?

Comment: It should be more or less equivalent to `new Object() == new Integer(0)` (or `new Integer(2)`).  It should never be an error, and always be `false` since the new `Object` can't be the same object as the `Integer` object.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux  Not really.  It's equivalent to `new Object() == Integer.valueOf(0)` and `new Object() == Integer.valueOf(2)`.  Both will always produce false, of course.

Comment: As I think about it, it was technically a bug in 1.6. But I think it will cause more trouble because the compiler won't warn you if you accidentally write something like this, instead of having the benefit of being allowed to write `a == 3`.

Comment: Would this mean that in `Object a = 10000; boolean b = a == 10000;`, b would be `false`? Because the Integer.valueOf cache only goes to 128.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux  Good point.  Compilers usually produce warnings for every autobox, but many people disables them almost by default, so we couldn't count on them.  On the other hand, you can make a similar mistake with references instead of numbers, and also this happens only with the `Object` class (and maybe `Number`).  Given that generics almost completely eliminated the (explicit) use of `Object`, the problem could be smaller than we think.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux  You keep making good points.  Yes:  in `Object a = 10000; boolean b = a == 10000;`, b would be false.  But in `Integer a = 10000; boolean b = a == 10000;`, b would be... true!!! (because of the autounboxing rules).

Comment: What is the reason for that? Is are any JLS section about this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a typo in my first ideone. Here is an updated version. So this means that instead of auto-boxing, auto-unboxing takes place in the last case of this test: http://ideone.com/FSAWxe

Comment: John Skeet found a reference to this behavior in the JLS. Check out his great answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1515811/155137. Everything is clear to me now :)

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux  That discussion is marginally related, as it refers to wrapper/wrapper comparisons and how to "make them work".  That has always been very clear.  Here we are talking reference / primitive.  Specially `Object` / primitive.  The referenced JLS chapters are obviously related because they are the ones on conversions and expressions.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just linked this answer because of the references to the JLS he put there. These JLS references explain why `Integer i = 1000; boolean b = i == 1000;` gives true.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux You and Mario, thanks for your comments, but I think it doesn't really answer my question. Does java 7 have a new major feature that supports and explains this behavior? Or is it just a hidden fix?

Comment: looks like JDK 1.8.* treats this as error again. (I personally think that it's good — code like this is a strong smell anyway)

Comment: A well-designed language will allow certain type conversions to be applied in some contexts but forbidden in others.  The simplistic notion that type conversions which are applicable anywhere should be applicable everywhere means that `double a=1234567890/10.0f;` will silently yield 123456792.0 rather than demanding that the programmer indicate more affirmatively what's really intended.  Accepting the notion that operators like `==` should be pickier than some others will make it practical to have conversion rules which are much more useful than would be rules that must apply everywhere.