# Why is an int-to-Object comparison valid in Java 7, but not in Java 8?

Tags: java

The following code,

```
private boolean compare(Object a, int b) {
    return a == b;
}
```

compiles in Java 7, but it results in the following error in Java 8:

> incomparable types: int and Object

Looking at the following question:

[Comparing Object and int in Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18500209/comparing-object-and-int-in-java-7)

It seems like Java 6 and Java 8 don't let you compare `int` and `Object`, while 7 does. Is there any documentation on this?

I'm interested in the background knowledge that informed these decisions. It seems like they were undecided or something.

I'm using [IntelliJ IDEA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) 14.1.4 with JDK 1.7.0.51.

Comment: Is the error shown in eclipse (ie. when using ecj) or by the JDK compiler? I'd guess this is an error in ecj...

Comment: If that's the case, I would think Java 7 made a mistake

Comment: With Oracle's Java 7, I get "Incompatible operand types: Object and int". Are you providing the exact code that you observed in compiled in Java 7?

Comment: @AndyThomas i´d guess it depends on the specific version of the 1.7 jdk. llogiq couldn´t compile with jdk 1.7.0_75 while wero could compile it with jdk 1.7.0_71. Maybe they did a bug fix in between these versions?

Comment: Compilation fails on jdk 1.7.0_67

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Java 7 applies autoboxing to the int.

```
 private boolean compare(java.lang.Object, int);
   Code:
      0: aload_1
      1: iload_2
      2: invokestatic  #2       // Method java/lang/Integer.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Integer;
      5: if_acmpne     12
      8: iconst_1
      9: goto          13
     12: iconst_0
     13: ireturn
```

I created this with `build 1.7.0_71-b14`

EDIT:

This behaviour was recognized and treated as bug by Oracle:
[JDK-8013357](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8013357): Javac accepts erroneous binary comparison operations

> Relevant JLS section is 15.21. Javac seems to treat this as a
>   reference comparison, but a reference comparison is only allowed when
>   BOTH operands are reference types.
>   
> ...
>   The type rules for binary comparisons in JLS Section 15.21 will now be
>   correctly enforced by javac.  Since **JDK5**, javac has accepted some
>   programs with Object-primitive comparisons that are incorrectly typed
>   according to JLS 15.21.  These comparisons will now be correctly
>   identified as type errors.

Answer (score 22):

The [JLS - Chapter 15. Equality Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21) mentions 3 different `==` operators: *numerical*, *boolean* and *reference*. **None** of the `==` operators can happen in your example, so we conclude that the statement **is illegal**.

Let's see why `==` cannot be applied in your example:

- [15.21.2. Boolean Equality Operators == and !=](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.2)

  No need to mention why it's not relevant..
- [15.21.3. Reference Equality Operators == and !=](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3)

  > If the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference type or the null type, then the operation is object equality.
  >
  > **It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other by a casting conversion ([§5.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5)). The run-time values of the two operands would necessarily be unequal.**
- [15.21.1. Numerical Equality Operators == and !=](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.1)

  > If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or one is of numeric type and the other is convertible ([§5.1.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8)) to numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands ([§5.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)).

Now let's assume it's legal and the compiler changed the line to:

```
if (a == new Integer(b))
```

What do you expect the result to be? The condition will never evaluate to `true`, so it makes sense that **it's a bug** that was fixed in Java 8.

Comment: However autoboxing is done using `Integer.valueOf`. Since `Integer.valueOf` sometimes returns values from a pool, the result could be `true`.

Comment: @fabian So, never true *in a reasonably useful or intuitive way*.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Well, for the code in the answer, it will definitely never be true. `new Integer(b)` always creates an object, whereas `Integer.valueOf(b)` might not.

Comment: As other commenters have said, this answer is wrong. Comparing an integer and Object is well defined with autoboxing.

Answer (score 7):

I could not get an example to compile (fixing bool → boolean) with javac 1.7.0_75, nor with javac 1.8.0_60. I don't have a JDK6, but I don't think it should have worked there either. Perhaps it is an earlier ecj incompatibility, as Axel hints, or a bug in a different minor version of javac.

In any event, if it works, it is due to autoboxing. This may have been pared back in preparation for Java 8, because streams and autoboxing don't mix too well.

Answer (score 5):

It shouldn't have compiled, according to [JLS 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21). `int` can be compared to boxed numeric types, i.e. Byte, Short, Character, Integer, Long, Float, Double. But that is all.

And if comparison is between `int` and say `Float`, `Float` will be unboxed first, so that the comparison is between `float` and `int`. It'll make no sense to do the other way around - box `int` then examine the identity of the `Integer` (with a `Float` no less).