# Linked List Delete Method

Tags: java, list

The following is a class definition for my Linked List.  I run a test program that creates a new LinkedList and inserts the numbers "3, 2, 1" and then prints the list.  This works fine.  However, when I try and delete "3" or "2," the delete method never completes.  When I try and delete "1," it just prints out the complete list as if nothing had been deleted.

```
public class LinkedListTest implements LinkedList {
private Node head;

public LinkedListTest(){
    head = new Node();
}

public void insert(Object x){
    if (lookup(x).equals(false)){

        if (head.data == null)
            head.data = x;

        else{
            //InsertLast
            Node temp = head;

            while (temp.next != null){
                temp = temp.next;
            }

            Node NewNode = new Node();
            NewNode.data = x;
            NewNode.next = null;

            temp.next = NewNode;

        }
    }
    //Runtime of insert method will be n, where n is the number of nodes
}

public void delete(Object x){
    if (lookup(x).equals(true)){
        if (head.data == x)
            head = head.next;

        else{
            Node temp = head;
            while (temp.next != null){
                if ((temp.next).data == x)
                    temp.next = (temp.next).next;
                else
                    temp = temp.next;
            }
        }

    }
}

public Object lookup(Object x){
    Node temp = head;
    Boolean search = false;

    if (head.data == x)
        search = true;

    while (temp.next != null){
        if (temp.data == x){
            search = true;
        }

        else{
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }

    return search;
}

public boolean isEmpty(){
    if (head.next == null && head.data == null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public void printList(){
    Node temp = head;
    System.out.print(temp.data + " ");

    while (temp.next != null){
        temp = temp.next;
        System.out.print(temp.data + " ");
    }

}
}
```

EDIT: Here is the node class:

```
public class Node {
public Object data;
public Node next;

public Node(){
    this.data = null;
    this.next = null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

The first big issue is that in your `lookup()` and your `delete()` methods, you don't break out of your loops when a successful condition occurs. This is why your program is hanging; it's in an infinite loop.

It's also worth noting a this point is that it's *an incredibly bad practice* not to use curly braces with all if/else statements. There's no reason not to do so, and it can introduce bugs easily when you don't.

in `lookup()` you should have:

```
if (head.data == x) {
    search = true;
} else {
    while (temp.next != null){
        if (temp.data == x){
            search = true;
            break;
        } else {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
}
```

and in `delete()`:

```
if (head.data == x) {
    head = head.next;
} else {
    Node temp = head;
    while (temp.next != null) {
        if (temp.next.data.equals(x)) {
            temp.next = temp.next.next;
            break;
        } else {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
}
```

Now this will produce what you expect:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) 
{
   LinkedListTest llt = new LinkedListTest();

   llt.insert(1);
   llt.insert(2);
   llt.insert(3);

   llt.printList();
   System.out.println();

   llt.delete(2);
   llt.printList();
}
```

Output:

> 1 2 3
>   1 3

However, that doesn't expose your second, larger issue. You're comparing **reference values** using `==` when looking at the node's `data`.

This "works" at the moment because of a side-effect of auto-boxing small integer values; you're getting the same object references. (String literals would also "work" because of the string pool). For more info on this, look at [How do I compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) and [When comparing two integers in java does auto-unboxing occur](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/when-comparing-two-integers-in-java-does-auto-unboxing-occur)

Let's look at this:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
   LinkedListTest llt = new LinkedListTest();

   llt.insert(1000);
   llt.insert(2000);
   llt.insert(2000);
   llt.insert(3000);

   llt.printList();
   System.out.println();

   llt.delete(2000);
   llt.printList();
}
```

Output:

> 1000 2000 2000 3000
>   1000 2000 2000 3000

`lookup()` stopped working, allowing a duplicate to be inserted. `delete()` stopped working as well.

This is because `int` values over 127 auto-box to unique `Integer` objects rather than cached ones (see the linked SO question above for a full explanation).

Anywhere you're using `==` to compare the value held by `data` needs to be changed to use `.equals()` instead.

```
if (temp.data.equals(x)) {
```

With those technical issues solved, your program will work. There's other things that you should consider though. The two that jump right out are:

- `lookup` should return a `boolean`.
- There's no need to call `lookup()` in `delete()`
- `lookup` itself is a fairly inefficient approach as a separate method; An insert iterates through the entire list twice.

Comment: I originally used .equals, but someone told me that was incorrect.  It seemed very wrong.

I also think lookup should be a boolean and that I don't need lookup in delete, but it's part of a lab and that's how I was told to do things.

Finally, thanks for this awesome answer! This was superbly helpful!

Comment: @ChristianBaker Glad I could help. I hate when I see asignments like this because ... yeah, they're just horrible :-D But in the end it's important to understand that variables holding Object reference values are basically the same thing as pointers in C; they contain a value that refers to something in memory. If you want to know if two variables refer to the same object in memory, use `==`. If you want to know if two objects in memory are considered equal due to what they contain, use `.equals()`

Comment: One last question, would it be okay to say if (head.data == null)?

Comment: @ChristianBaker Yes. `null` is actually a (special) reference value. It means the variable isn't holding a reference to an object in memory (which is what you're checking for there).

Answer (score 0):

First of all why does lookup return an object? change it to boolean.
also your "while" loop in `lookup()` doesn't advance. you need to remove the "else".
your delete function seems fine though.

Answer (score -1):

I think you got quite some things wrong.

First of all, when you use LinkedList all of the functionality you tried to implement already exists.

Furthermore your style is relatively bad. For example, why do you use the WrapperClass Boolean for lookup?

Combining functionality like *contains* with something like *get* in one method is not a good idea. Split this up in two methods, let *contains* just return a boolean and test if an element exists in the list. Let get search and return for an element.

In addition to this you try to compare the Objects via equal. If you have not overwritten equals you can not delete anything ever, because equals needs reference equality which is not given most times.

I would highly recommend that you buy a java book or something to improve your overall knowledge..

Comment: This is part of a lab.  I was asked to create my own implementation of linked list, and I had to implement an interface that had lookup return a boolean.

Comment: yes, but your lookup method does only return a Boolean wrapper class, not a boolean (primitive datatype). The signature of lookup should be *boolean lookup(Object x)* and the declaration/initilization of search  should go like this *boolean search = false;*
This would create a boolean (primitive dataytpe) rather than a Boolean (wrapper class)

Comment: Welp, I'm stupid.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Idk why I'm having it return a Boolean.