# Sorting with Comparator and Arrays.asList()

Tags: java, arrays, collections, comparator

When I execute below code, I am getting output as `[0, -2000000000, 2000000000]`.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SordidSort {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Integer big = new Integer(2000000000);
    Integer small = new Integer(-2000000000);
    Integer zero = new Integer(0);
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[] { big, small, zero };
    Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Object>() {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return ((Integer) o2).intValue() - ((Integer) o1).intValue();
        }
    });
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));
    }
}
```

How it sorted the numbers?

Comment: Exactly the way you specify it to do, with the twist that an `int` can't hold a value of `(-)4000000000`, so you get an overflow. Try using smaller numbers, or a `long`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to properly compare two Integers in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/how-to-properly-compare-two-integers-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    return ((Integer) o2).intValue() - ((Integer) o1).intValue();
}
```

Use the following

```
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    int x1 = ((Integer) o1).intValue();
    int x2 = ((Integer) o2).intValue();
    if (x1 < x2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (x1 == x2) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Your code can generate an overflow. When an overflow is generated you can obtain strange order.

Comment: What about ((Integer) o1).compareTo((Integer) o2) ?

Comment: In effect it is not necessary at all a Comparator. This is the natural order of Integer. This is only to enphatize where the problem comes with int - int

Answer (score 0):

There are some subtleties in manual implementation of comparator. You've just hit some regarding the `int` type. It's much more difficult to compare two `float` or `double` values correctly. If you don't handle `-0.0` you may have `0.0` and `-0.0` misordered. And if you don't handle `NaN`, it may lead to disaster (random order after sorting, broken `TreeMap`, etc.). Luckily there are ready static methods named `compare` in every boxed type: `Integer.compare` (since Java 7), `Double.compare`, `Float.compare` and so on. Use them, and you will never have such problems.

Since Java 8 implementing comparators is much simpler: you have ready helper methods like `Comparator.comparingInt`:

```
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparingInt(o -> ((Integer)o).intValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follow ::

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SordidSort {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Integer big = new Integer(2000000000);
        Integer small = new Integer(-2000000000);
        Integer zero = new Integer(0);
        Integer[] arr = new Integer[] { big, small, zero };
        Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Object>() {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {

                int o1Val = ((Integer) o1).intValue();
                int o2Val = ((Integer) o2).intValue();

                if(o1Val > o2Val){
                    return 1;
                } else if(o1Val == o2Val){
                    return 0;
                }else{
                    return -1; 
                }
            }
        });
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare your Comparator as `new Comparator<Integer>()`  so that you are passing `Integer`s to your compare function, you can then benefit from the `Integer.compareTo` method

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Integer big = new Integer(2000000000);
    Integer small = new Integer(-2000000000);
    Integer zero = new Integer(0);
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[] { big, small, zero };
    Arrays.sort(arr, new Comparator<Integer>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
      }
    });
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(arr));
  }
```