# Comparing students according to score JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, int, comparator

I have a class of Student. The class has `String name`, `int studentId` and `int studentScore`. I want to compare the students in `ArrayList<Student> students` according to the studentscore. This means if "student 1" and "student 2" has the same amount of studentscore then both of their ranks will be the same. I have a function where I set The rank. But I'm unsure how to compare everything in the arraylist.

When I search for comparing int values I get the results:

[How to properly compare two Integers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/how-to-properly-compare-two-integers-in-java)

I think the best solution will be to use comparator class function. But Im unsure how to do this because I'm unsure of the comparator classes capability. I was think of for looping getting a player by that loop then for looping again and comparing. But this doesnt seem like a good solution.

> I want this result:

Say that the array of students contains (name,studentscore) is:

```
(kim, 12), (werder, 20), (ben, 32), (sara, 12)
```

I want the rank of the student to be (If ASC order):

```
kim: rank = 1
werder: 2
ben: 3
sara: 1
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? ordering by score, or ordered grouping by score? Please post a simple example of input, desired result, and what did you try so far.

Comment: what will be returned in this case, is it the first score in asc order?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I have updated my question. hope it gives better clarity

Comment: yes, now it is clear. Please see my suggested answer how can you use a custom comparator and apply ranks by positions in a sorted list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use java Stream (Java 8).
Better way to do this. 
You can found a really good exemple at : http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/007-sort-arraylist-stream-of-objects-in-java8/

Answer (score 1):

You may first students by score using [`Comparator.somparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) comparator, then iterate over sorted list and apply ranks, as follows:

```
Collection<Student> students =  // ... your collection of students

// copy students to a new List
List<Student> ordered = new ArrayList<>(students);

// sort by score
Collections.sort(ordered, Comparator.comparing(Student::getScore));

// set rank 1 to first item, i. e. having the lowest score
int rank = 1;
ordered.get(0).setRank(rank);
for (int i = 1; i < ordered.size(); i++) {
    // increment rank only if score changed
    // in order to apply same ranks to same scores
    if (ordered.get(i).getScore() != ordered.get(i - 1).getScore())
        rank++;
    ordered.get(i).setRank(rank);
}
```

If you'd need lower ranks to be assigned to higher scores, just apply `.reversed()` to a comparator:

```
Collections.sort(ordered, Comparator.comparing(Student::getScore).reversed());
```

---

To create a comparator in Java prior 1.8, you need to instantiate an anonymous `Comparator` where `.compare()` method is implemented:

```
Comparator<Student> cmp = new Comparator<Student>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Student s1, Student s2) {
        return s1.getScore().compareTo(s2.getScore());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was planning on doing after I read [link](http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/007-sort-arraylist-stream-of-objects-in-java8/)   I tried this right now but I'm getting an error at `Comparator.comparing(Student::getScore))` I get this message when I hover over`(Student::getScore)` : "method reference are not supported at this language level" and red text at `comparing` saying "cannot resolve method comparing(<method reference>) " Im using android Studio running at apk ver 16.

Comment: @CookieMonster it means that you use Java prior to 1.8. I will update to show how to create a custom comparator in earlier Java.

Comment: I tired the workaround, and I get red text at `compareTo` saying "cannot resolve method compareTo(int)", can this also be a java version problem?

Comment: Oh, I misspelled. It should be `s1.getScore() - s2.getScore()` if score is `int`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to be able to sort your `ArrayList<Student>` based on the `studentScore`.

You can have the student class implement `Comparable()`

```
public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    private String name;
    private int studentId;
    private int studentScore;

public int compareTo(Contact other) {
    return studentScore.compareTo(other.studentScore);
}
```

Then you can do

```
ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>;
// Insert you students into the array
// students.add(someStudent)
Collections.sort(students);
```

Note that this is the `Comparable` interface which requires you to implement the method `compareTo()`. You only need the `Comparator` interface if you want to impose a *total ordering*, for example to order objects that do not have some *natural ordering*.

The students should then be sorted in ascending order in the list, so that  the first element in the list the "smallest".

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to deal with your issue. You can make your class to implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, and then it would have a method `compareTo()`. But then you will need to worry that your `compareTo()` method is consistent with `equals()` method. That means that you will need to override your `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods. That might be a bit too much.

The other way about it is to create your own Comparator that would implement an interface [Comporator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). All you will need to do is to impllement method `int compare(T o1, T o2)` and then just use `Collections`'s [public static  void sort(List list,
                            Comparator c)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-java.util.Comparator-) method.
Once you sort your array it will be easy just to iterate through it and assign appropriate ranks