# Comparing two Integers 'Unnecessary unboxing' warning

Tags: java

I try to compare Integers the next way (for my case, it's good):

```
public void compareMayNull(Integer a, Integer b) {
    if ((a == null ? -1 : a.intValue()) == b.intValue())
        System.out.println("true");
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA gives me warning 'Unnecessary unboxing' on `a.intValue()` and `b.intValue()` and recommend me to simplify code to this:

```
public void compareMayNull(Integer a, Integer b) {
    if ((a == null ? -1 : a) == b)
        System.out.println("true");
}
```

But I'm little confused, because references will be compared if `a != null` that not best practice as I know. What code should I use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/how-to-properly-compare-two-integers-in-java

Comment: Since you assume that `b` cannot be `null`, how about `if(b.equals(a == null ? -1 : a))` ?

Comment: If `b` cannot be `null`, you could also make this explicit by changing the signature to `compareMayNull(Integer a, int b)`

Comment: What if `b.intValue() == -1`?

Comment: Impossible in my case.

Comment: @delver there's just no need for the restriction: `if (a != null && a.intValue() == b.intValue())` handles all integer values. (You might also want to check that `b` isn't null).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you have a `-1` *literal* which is an `int` type, `a` will be *auto-unboxed*, (if and only if `a == null` is `false` else the expression is not evaluated) in the evaluation of the ternary conditional

`a == null ? -1 : a;`

Then since this *expression* is of type `int`, `b` is also *auto-unboxed*.

Therefore you can write `if ((a == null ? -1 : a) == b)`, safe in the knowledge that Java will auto-unbox both `a` and `b`. So your explicit unboxing via the calls to `intValue()` is superfluous and your IDE is warning you of this. For the avoidance of doubt `a` is **not** auto-unboxed when the expression `a == null` is evaluated.

Personally I find this to be one of the most pernicious parts of Java. I'd seriously consider writing it the way you originally had it, and tell your IDE to suck it.

Comment: What do you think about `if (!(a != null && a.intValue() == b.intValue()))`?

Comment: Personally I'd use `a.equals(b)`.

Comment: Equivalent to, but more complex than `if (a == null || a.intValue() != b.intValue())`

Comment: @delver in case you've not seen that transformation before, it's an application of [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws): `!(a && b) == !a || !b`.

Answer (score -1):

```
compareMayNull(Integer a, Integer b)
```

should do other than returning void...

maybe an int will be fine so you can do

```
(a == null ? -1 : a.compareTo(b)
```