# Java - Sorting integers from objects in an ArrayList

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have populated an ArrayList with Boat objects. The boat has a name, an ID and a score. I need to compare the scores, integers, with eachother and order them from lowest to highest.

I've tried a lot, and failed a lot and I'm stumped on what to do.

```
public class Boat {
private String name;
private int id;
private int score;

//Constructor
public Boat(String name, int id, int score) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.score = score;
}
```

I've found the Comparator class, but can't figure out how to use it properly.

Basically what I need to do is to sort the scores into a new ArrayList. Moving them from my `private ArrayList<Boat> participants;` list to my `private ArrayList<Boat> sortedScoreList;` list in descending order.

This is my first time posting on here, so please let me know if I need to add more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Comparator in Java to sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort)

Comment: I think your question contradicts itself. Do you want descending, or lowest to highest?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly compare two Integers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/how-to-properly-compare-two-integers-in-java)

Comment: I meant from lowest to highest score, so ascending... Too tired to think I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the default `sort` method to sort by `score` ascending:

```
ArrayList<Boat> sortedScoreList = new ArrayList<>(participants);
sortedScoreList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Boat::getScore));
```

Using the default `sort` method to sort by `score` descending:

```
ArrayList<Boat> sortedScoreList = new ArrayList<>(participants);
sortedScoreList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Boat::getScore).reversed());
```

Using steams to sort by `score` ascending:

```
ArrayList<Boat> sortedScoreList = 
            participants.stream()
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Boat::getScore))
                        .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Using steams to sort by `score` descending:

```
ArrayList<Boat> sortedScoreList =
            participants.stream()
                        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Boat::getScore).reversed())
                        .collect(toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I've been banging my head against the wall for so long. Now I'm just embarrassed when I look at what I tried to do and what the solution was... hah