# compare two integer with == is ok, why not double？

Tags: java

```
Integer int1 = 2;
Integer int2 = 2;
System.out.println(int1 == int2);   // ok
```

Run code

```
/Libray/.../jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/.../..java...
true
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Compare Double object

```
Double dou1 = 4.0;
Double dou2 = 4.0;
System.out.println(dou1 == dou2);
```

Run code

```
/Libray/.../jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/.../..java...
false
Process finished with exit code 0
```

I think it's possible to compare integers using autoboxing and unboxing, but why it doesn't work for Double?

Comment: Try the first one with larger integer values.

Comment: `Integer`s are objects. They should be compared with `.equals`. Two Integer objects with the same value might _happen_ to be the same object, but that should not be relied upon.

Comment: If I recall correctly Integers from -128 to 127 are shared objects. For other ones new objects are created. Doing comparison from outside of that range will result in false as well.

Comment: Integers are cached and reused in range -128 .. 127. If you use `==` to compare integers outside of that ranged you will get false.

Comment: @Amongalen i try it more then 127,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/how-to-properly-compare-two-integers-in-java