# Convert Text File into List and Access elements of List by Index not by Iteration

Tags: java, list, file, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I try several times to convert the text in a File into List and print some elements of the List according to reference index but I can't, it throws IndexOutOfBounds Exception: index 3 , Size 1

is there any possible way to overcome the situation.

```
myTEXT.txt

BUK,2023,IS,COMMING
```

my Code

```
List<String> TexttoList = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    FileReader scores = new FileReader("myTEXT.txt");
    
    Scanner scanText = new Scanner(myTEXT);
    scanText.useDelimiter(",\\s*");
    
    while(scanText.hasNext()) {
        
        
        for(int d = 0; d<4; d++){
        TexttoList.add(d , scanText.next());
        System.out.println(TexttoList.get(3));
        //IndexOutOfBounds Exception: index 4 , Size 1
        }
    }
```

it only prints First index(0) and return the entire text

```
    BUK
    2023
    IS
    COMMING
```

Comment: Sure this is your actual code? `B.add(A);` wouldn't compile - it should be `B.addAll(A);`.

Comment: Your code won't compile. `B` is an `ArrayList` of `Double` type but you are trying to add another `ArrayList A` in to this `ArrayList`. You probably meant to add the elements of `A` in `B`. You also have a typo in the last line of code: `System.out.Println`

Comment: "Please What is my Problem ?" - have a look at what `==` means for objects (and why you should use `equals()` instead). You should also learn to step through your code with a debugger and have a look at those `if-if-if...` sequences. Finally, your code looks _very_ odd and fragile, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: when i run your code (with little fix like B.addAll(A), or println without capital P ) i have the following result : 2nd 1st 5th 4th 3rd

Comment: _I run the Code and gives me this output [1st , 2nd , 3rd , 4th , 5th]_ - your code won't compile but if you fix the errors, your code will not produce the output that you are claiming that it produces.

Comment: Yes I want add the Element of A in B

Comment: So Now how can I achieve the this output [ 1st , 1st , 3rd , 4th , 4th ] in my code

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator compares the references. You should use the `.equals()` function instead to compare the values.

for example, `A.get(a).equals(B.get(4))`

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1515811/12726948) for details.

Comment: Thank You A.get(a).equals(B.get(4)) Works Accurately.

Comment: Thank You A.get(a).equals(B.get(4)) Works Accurately.      My Sincere Great to Thomas who highlights me to check my Sequence of if--if--if Statements        Thank You all