# Need to check if the last number in an ArrayList is repeated in the other part of the ArrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, java.util.scanner

The title describes what I am trying to do.

The code doesn't have any errors, but it doesn't output true/false at the right times. For example, for the input

5
1
2
3
4
5
done

the output will be false, which is incorrect because you can see that 5 appears at the end and in another location in the ArrayList. So yeah, I could use some help de-bugging and I appreciate the help!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LastRunner {

    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        
        System.out.println("Enter some numbers. When done, type \"done\"");
        
        while (s.hasNextInt()) 
        {
            list.add(s.nextInt());
        }
        
        int size = list.size();
        boolean lastChecker = false;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < size-1; i++)
        {
            if (list.get(size-1) == list.get(i))
            {
                lastChecker = true;
            }
        } 
        
        System.out.println(lastChecker);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code is working fine as per the input you have given , it's returning true itself. Check again

Answer (score 0):

It is plausible that your program works for the input in your question.  (As noted in a comment.  I have not actually tried it, but I can see why it *would* work.)

However, there is definitely a bug in your program.  The problem I found is here:

```
     if (list.get(size-1) == list.get(i))
```

The problem is that `list.get` will return an `Integer` object.  But when you use `==` to compare two `Integer` objects, you are actually comparing two object references.

Comparing two `Integer` values using `==` only works some of the time.  It will depend on the values and how they were created.

The correct way to write the above line is:

```
    if (list.get(size-1).equals(list.get(i)))
```

(Note: if you managed to get a `null` in the list, the above might give you an NPE.  However, I would NOT recommend testing for `null`.  A `null` in your list would be a sign that there was a bug in the code that is building the list.  So it is better to let the NPE happen ... so that the programmer will get a bug report, or whatever.)

---

For a more detailed explanation of why `Integer == Integer` is incorrect (and why it sometimes works), see the dup link: [How to properly compare two Integers in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/how-to-properly-compare-two-integers-in-java).