# Why java Integers not equal when using getValue() and get()

Tags: java

Why do I need the extra step to make it intValue in order for them to equal?

Is it because it is comparing if it is the same object?

```
        Map<Integer, Integer> m1 = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
        Map<Integer, Integer> m2 = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

        m1.put(1, 1000);
        m2.put(2, 1000);

        for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> mmm : m1.entrySet()) {
            if (mmm.getValue() == m2.get(2)) {
                 System.out.println("I should be equal");
            }
            if (mmm.getValue().intValue() == m2.get(2).intValue()) {
                 System.out.println("but im equal");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What does `Integer i1 = 1000; Integer i2 = 1000; System.out.println("eq: " + (i1 == i2))` give? Why might that be the case? [This question on comparing Integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1514910/how-to-properly-compare-two-integers-in-java) gives some hints.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the statement

```
mmm.getValue() == m2.get(2)
```

checks whether both refer to the same object, not the values within them.
To compare values something like this can also be done:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> m1 = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> m2 = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

    m1.put(1, 1000);
    m2.put(2, 1000);

    for (Map.Entry<Integer,Integer> mmm : m1.entrySet()) {
        if (mmm.getValue().compareTo(m2.get(2)) == 0) {
             System.out.println("I should be equal");
        }
        if (mmm.getValue().intValue() == m2.get(2).intValue()) {
             System.out.println("but im equal");
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you just want to test for equality `equals` will probably be faster than `compareTo`.  And definitely simpler and more readable.